# SIEM: Correlating remote logons to associate origin and target user

Tags: authentication, siem, identity-management

How is it possible to correlate or detect user logons, e.g. via ssh/rdp, to associate the origin user and target user?

My use case is to know who actually (personal/identifiable) used a technical account (non-personal).

Sidenote: Both clients and both users are in the same network and or at least share the same AD forrest or authentication.

Comment: It is going to depend on what data is available in your logs

Comment: Take for example windows event logging with Event 4624 User Logon Type 10 (remote connections). Or syslog (eg with process starts for ssh)

Comment: What SIEM are you using? It depends on your logs and how they are structured. ie having logs structured in the Universal Event Format (UEF) before sending to InsightIDR..

Answer (score 2):

SIEM correlation rules generally require matching or corresponding attributes in a log in order to link 2 logs together. So one option may be to match on ip addreses. Perhaps it's a timing rule such that a remote (personal) account logs in and a log shows they are assigned an internal ip. Then the rule says that if within 5 minutes that internal ip logs into another system with a different account (technical) then report it to you. Now you have an alert that correlates the personal account to the technical account.

Example:

Log1: vpn says user1 remoted in from 8.8.8.8 & was assigned ip 10.0.0.1

Log2: Linux server says technicalaccount1 ssh'd I'm from 10.0.0.1

Alert: Linux ssh within 5 minutes after vpn login with matching ips